# DATAADAPTERS AND NULLS

Tags: c#, sql, null, sqldataadapter

I am trying to pass a null to DataAdapter.Fill. My SQL statement accepts nulls but I get a return that nulls are not acceptable.

```
JUEGO.etreDataSetTableAdapters.CountyTableAdapter etreDataSetCountyTableAdapter = new          JUEGO.etreDataSetTableAdapters.CountyTableAdapter();
        etreDataSetCountyTableAdapter.Fill(etreDataSet.County, null);
        CollectionViewSource CViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("CViewSource")));
        CViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
```

the CountryTableAdapter has the SQL Statement below behind it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CCODE FROM  HH_Match WHERE  (@DCODE IS NULL OR DCODE = @DCODE)
```

but when I pass Null like above it returns a massage that nulls are not allowed. I am working in Visual Studio (C#) 2012. Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the `TableAdapter` manually so that it accepts null.

Therefore click on `Parameters` in the query property. Select the parameter you want to make optionally (in this case you have only one parameter). On the right side you'll find `AllowDbNull`. Set this to `True` and you've arrived.

[image]

Comment: Tim where do I find that GUI in VS 2012

Comment: @DeoMutyaba: But you have created your typed `DataSet`, haven't you? Click on the `xsd` file and you are in the designer. Then search the `TableAdapter` with the name `CountyTableAdapter`. Below it you find the queries, by default `Fill` and `GetData`. Right click it and select _properties_. There you find the _parameters_. Click it on see the gui above (probably in english). Note that i have VS 2010 but i doubt that anything was changed.